# How do I display a Web Forms page from an MVC 2 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The Report Viewer control apparently only works in a Web Forms page (I'm using MVC 2).  So, I make one, add my report to it, and try making a link to it from one of the Views in my MVC 2 site.  I consistently get the error "The resource cannot be found".  I've tried every possible URL I can think of it get it to work.  I even dragged and dropped a Hyperlink tool into the page and set it to link to the Web Form in question and got the same results.

The Web Form is in the /Views/MaintenanceReports folder.  I've tried URLs such as ~/Views/MaintenanceReports/DriverList.aspx (with and without the *.aspx) and a few others.  But, I'm very sure this should be the URL.

I also added this page route to the Global.asax file in hopes that it would do something magical `routes.MapPageRoute("DriverListing", "MaintenanceReports/DriverListing", "~/Views/MaintenanceReports/DriverListing.aspx");`

I also tried adding, per the suggestion of one of my fellow programmers, an iframe to an MVC View that had the Web Form in question as its source.  This also gave me the same error.

I've got the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 on hand and it doesn't give me anything that helps.  It basically says that there shouldn't be an issue.

The server runs IIS 7 and has the .NET 4 framework installed.

Normally I'd spend more time looking for an answer, but I'm quite pressed for time currently.  This is my last day here (internship) and I'd like to get this last thing done before I leave.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `StopRoutingHandler`. I think the issue is you need to tell MVC to ignore those urls.

```
routes.Add(new Route("MaintenanceReports/{*resource}", 
                     new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

**Update**

It looks like the above doesn't work for routing within the `Views` folder. The simple solution is to move the `WebForms` out of the `Views` folder, and the `WebForms` work out of the box alongside MVC.

Comment: Hmmm...Now it ignores all those routes.  Clicking the "Maintenance Reports" link now also gives me the same error instead of taking me to the index page.  I think you're onto the right idea though.

Comment: Can you post your routing, works for me without any additional routing rules. Ah just noticed you actually have it in the Views folder, that's the issue.

Comment: Do you mean the stuff in the global.asax file?  I haven't screwed around with any of the routing at all.  It's still using the default format.

Comment: If you move it out of the views folder it will just work, is that an option?

Comment: Well, we're making progress.  I now get parser errors ("Unknown server tag 'rsweb:reportviewer'").  Yeah!  Progress!

Comment: Yes, Report Viewer is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this line into  to display a .asxp page

```
 <httpHandlers>
  <!-- see below -->
  <clear />
  <add  path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>  
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```